# Ho w to rename column value in incremental manner for string in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, auto-increment

**Input dataset:**

[image]

**Expected output dataset:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark.sql import functions as sf

spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("test").getOrCreate()

simpleData = (("XYZ",  2), \
              ("XYZ",  4), \
              ("XYZ",  10), \
              ("ABC",  6), \
              ("ABC",  8), \
              ("ABC",  18), \
              ("YYY",  20), \
              )

columns = ["Product_name", "Price"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=simpleData, schema=columns)

from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import row_number
windowSpec  = Window.partitionBy("Product_name").orderBy("Price")

ndf=df.withColumn("row_number",row_number().over(windowSpec)) \
    .withColumn("Product_name", sf.concat_ws('_',sf.col("Product_name"),sf.col("row_number")))\
    .drop('row_number').show()
```

OutPut:
[image]